# Cannot access object's methods from within event handler using `this`

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Below is my code for FF Extension monitoring browsing behaviour.
I can't access `trim` method from `processClick` method handling click event.

Console shows `this.trim` is not a function. 
I know that it maybe something with `this` scope.

I will be really grateful for any help.

```
function bbm(doc)
{
    this.doc = doc;

    this.registerListeners = function() {
        this.doc.addEventListener("click", this.processClick, false);
    };

    this.trim = function(str)
    {
        return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') ;
    };


    this.processClick = function(e) {
        alert(e.type + " " + this.trim(this.url));
    };

};
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/addeventlistener-this

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(obj) {   
    var _method = this;
    return function() {
        return _method.apply(obj, arguments);
    };    
}
```

Then,

```
this.registerListeners = function() {
     this.doc.addEventListener("click", this.processClick.bind(this), false);
};
```