# When I add an onclick event that references a method attached to an object, the method seems to lose all the properties associated with that object

Tags: javascript, events, object, methods

I want to be able to pass one object to another, then set up events that execute different methods from the initial object.

```
var TEST = {}; 
//User-created object
TEST.testObj = function () { this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); };
TEST.testObj.prototype = {
    initialize: function(a) {   
        this.a = a;
    },
    sayHi: function() {
    alert(a);
}
} 
//Menu accosiated with that class of objects 
TEST.testMenu = function () { this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); };
TEST.testMenu.prototype = {
    initialize: function(obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
        var menuItem = document.createElement('div');
        menuItem.innerHTML = 'Say Hi!';
        menuItem.onclick = this.obj.sayHi;
        document.body.appendChild(menuItem);
    }
}

t1 = new TEST.testObj('Test Object');
menu = new TEST.testMenu(t1);
```

Activating the event by clicking the div alerts undefined. It looks like it's calling the function sayHi, but a generic one not associated with an instantiated object.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use a short, descriptive title...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access object's methods from within event handler using `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466274/cannot-access-objects-methods-from-within-event-handler-using-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a sayHi() function declared in this code. Just add this line

```
TEST.testObj.prototype.sayHi = function() {alert('hi')}
```

after the `TEST.testObj.prototype...` part. This will create a new function in TEST's prototype chain that you can call inside the testMenu object

**EDIT**
The way you are binding the onclick event, *this* was referring to the div HTML element, not the object. This is the changed code that should work:

```
var TEST = {}; 
        //User-created object
        TEST.testObj = function () { this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); };
        TEST.testObj.prototype = {
            a: null, 
            initialize: function(a) {
                this.a = a;
            },
            sayHi: function() {
            alert(this.a);
        }
        } 
        //Menu accosiated with that class of objects 
        TEST.testMenu = function () { this.initialize.apply(this, arguments); };
        TEST.testMenu.prototype = {
            initialize: function(obj) {
                this.obj = obj;
                var menuItem = document.createElement('div');
                menuItem.innerHTML = 'Say Hi!';
                menuItem.onclick = function() { obj.sayHi(); }
                document.body.appendChild(menuItem);
            }
        }

        t1 = new TEST.testObj('Test Object');
        menu = new TEST.testMenu(t1);
```

Comment: Hey, my bad I just noticed that I mess up when I copy and pasted it. Edited to include the function.  Thing is, I want to alert a property of the testObj object. It's coming up undefined. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer. The problem was essentially in the onclick binding event. Another issue was that you were referring to the a variable, which is undefined, instead of this.a

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I thought I had a pretty good handle on _this_, I'll have to read up on it more.

Comment: Yeah this is kinda not-so-easy-to-understand. This is why kids this days can't live without jQuery and stuff. Not that jQuery is a bad thing, not at all. Just a little more understanding of javascript in general would've been a nice thing to have around. Good luck :)