# Concept - What does `this` refer to in an addEventListener callback?

Tags: javascript

This function does not work..can't figure out why...no errors...but the image does not shrink when I click it.

```
image_element.addEventListener( "click", function( )
{ 
    this.style.width = ( parseInt( this.style.width ) - 1 ) + 'px';
    this.style.height = ( parseInt( this.style.height ) - 1 ) + 'px';
}, false );
```

Comment: Are you asking for help with your code?  Or what "this" refers to inside the anonymous function?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Please keep the question/title related. I have updated the title with the question based on the comment. If there is another question, please refine it (knowing what `this` refers to now), then post a [new] related question/title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/addeventlistener-this -- pay attention to "event source" vs "element event was attached to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this`, in the context of an eventListener, is the element [that raised the event]. An issue you might have is that `this.style.width` may not be specified yet...

Log/alert the value of `this.style.width` and see what's in there in the first place.

Comment: Note that `this` refers to the element which **raised the event**, which might not be the element the event was attached to!

Answer (score 1):

```
image_element.addEventListener( "click", function( )
{ 
    var iWidth  = parseInt(this.style.width.substr(0, this.style.width.length-2), 10);
    var iHeight = parseInt(this.style.height.substr(0, this.style.height.length-2), 10);

    this.style.width  = (parseInt(iWidth  - 1, 10)) + 'px';
    this.style.height = (parseInt(iHeight - 1, 10)) + 'px';
}, false );
```

Comment: you does not have to trim the `px` using substr just `parseInt()` the value

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` refers to who triggered the event, in this case is a `DOM Element`

But your issue is because the style is `undefined` while you don't initialize it. So you should use the "ComputedStyle" to get the current value even if you haven't initialized it.

```
image_element.addEventListener( "click", function( )
{ 
    this.style.width = ( getStyle(this,'width',true) - 1 ) + 'px';
    this.style.height = ( getStyle(this,'height',true) - 1  ) + 'px';
}, false );
```

attach this function to your document:

```
/** Get the current computed style of an element */
function getStyle(element, strCssRule, returnInt){
    if(typeof element==="string"){element=document.getElementById(element);}
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(element.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){ return p1.toUpperCase(); });
        strValue = element.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    if(returnInt===true){ strValue=parseInt(strValue); }
    return strValue;
}
```

Comment: its all javascript in this answer, what do you mean?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist this should addresses your issue of uninitialized height/width css properties. Have a look at what the second code block does... it ascertains what the computed style is.

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery:

```
function initOrbs()
{
    var image_element = document.createElement( 'img' );
        $(image_element).addClass("orb");
        image_element.id = icon_array[ initOrbs.index ];
        image_element.speed = icon_array[ initOrbs.index + 1 ];
        if(image_element.speed  > 10000 )
        {
            image_element.speed  = image_element.speed / 10;
            $(image_element).width(20);
            $(image_element).height(20);
        }
        image_element.src = '/develop/foo/favicons/' + icon_array[ initOrbs.index ];  
        image_element.style.top = '-80px';
        image_element.style.left = random( 100, 800) + 'px';
        sky.appendChild( image_element );
        $(image_element).click( function()
        { 
            $(this).width( parseInt( $(this).width() ) - 1 );
            $(this).height( parseInt( $(this).height() ) - 1 );
        });
        moveLinear( image_element );
        initOrbs.index += 2;
}
```

Comment: there's no jquery tag in the question

Comment: That doesn't mean he can't use it.  When I was a beginner, I never used jQuery, but I was suggested to and now I always use jQuery

Comment: You're only doing a disservice to a novice by offering a library in response to a very basic question about javascript...

Comment: Your code can be jQuery free without adding more than ~15 characters... fail. http://jsfiddle.net/MmdwM/