# Why does removeeventlistener not work in this object context?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working on a game and I would like to abstract my UI, and bind unbind events based on various game states. But I can't figure out why this event is not being removed. It seems the scope is correct in the handler.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DhDSf/7/)

relevant (stripped down) js:

```
var controls = {
    game : {
        el : null,
        cb : null,
    
        bind : function(el, cb) {
            this.el = el;
            this.cb = cb;
            this.el.addEventListener('click', this.handler.bind(this), true);
        },
    
        unbind : function() {
            console.log('unbind');
            this.el.removeEventListener('click', this.handler, true);
        },
       
        handler : function() {
            this.cb();
            this.unbind();
        }
    }
};

var manager = {
    init : function() {
        var c = document.getElementById('c');
        controls.game.bind(c, this.action.bind(this));
    },

    action : function() {
        console.log('c clicked');
    }
};
manager.init();
```

And yet if I remove the event this way it works:

```
(...)

bind : function(el, cb) {
    this.el = el;
    this.cb = cb;
    var self = this;
    this.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.cb();
        self.el.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, true);
    }, true);
}

(...)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.bind` returns a **new** function. `this.handler.bind(this) !== this.handler`! You would have to store a reference to the new function somehow.

For example, storing a reference in a variable and using a closure:

```
var handler = this.handler.bind(this);
this.el.addEventListener('click', handler, true);

this.unbind = function() {
    this.el.removeEventListener('click', handler, true);
}
```

As alternative to `arguments.callee`, you could also give the function a name:

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', function handler() {
    self.cb();
    self.el.removeEventListener('click', handler, true);
}, true);
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the quick response. I was unaware of .bind creating a new function. :)

Comment: why not? -> this.el.addEventListener('click', this.handler.bind(this), true); and this.el.removeEventListener('click', this.handler.bind(this), true);

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña: I have explained this in my answer. `.bind` always returns a new (i.e. different) function.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of playing with binding which also requires more memory I'd recommend using [the following](https://web.archive.org/web/20200203061532/http://ajaxian.com/archives/an-alternative-way-to-addeventlistener):

```
var song = {
    handleEvent: function (event) {
      switch (event.type) {
        case: "click":
          console.log(this.name);
          break;
      }
    },
    name: "Yesterday"
};

songNode.addEventListener("click", song);
songNode.click(); // prints "Yesterday" into console
```

You can use an object `obj` that has `handleEvent` property as a handler on any DOM object to catch its events and have event handler's context set to that object `obj` without the use of `Function.prototype.bind`.

That way you can also remove handlers, so

```
songNode.removeEventListener("click", song);
```

Comment: +1 good suggestion, though I don't think that one or two more functions have any significant impact on the memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks. Depends on how many objects will end up using the bound versions of function, but yeah, it's not the memory that is of main advantage here :-)