# How to add parameter to bound function created through .bind(this)?

Tags: javascript, object, bind, addeventlistener

I have added an event listener that points to a method of the current object. Because the context of `this` was lost, I binded the method. From what I understand, `.bind(this)` [creates a new bound function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15819293/5916475), which means to remove the event listener, I have to keep the bound function in a variable for future use.

```
MyObject.prototype.addListener = function () {
    var checkAnchorBound = this.checkAnchor.bind(this);
    //anAnchorElement points to an anchor tag on the page
    this.anAnchorElement.addEventListener("click", checkAnchorBound);
}
```

Now, whenever I click that anchor, checkAnchor runs and everything works perfectly. The problem is removing the event listener because that event listener needs to be removed inside `this.removeListener` which is called by `this.checkAnchor`. That means I cannot pass the bound function as a parameter.

```
MyObject.prototype.removeListener = function (event) {
    //I cannot pass checkAnchorBound from MyObject.addListener as parameter
    this.anAnchorElement.removeEventListener("click", checkAnchorBound);
}
```

I tried storing `checkAnchorBound` in the object so I would not have to pass the variable as a parameter like so:

```
MyObject.prototype.addListener = function () {
    this.checkAnchorBound = this.checkAnchor.bind(this);
    //anAnchorElement points to an anchor tag on the page
    this.anAnchorElement.addEventListener("click", this.checkAnchorBound);
}
```

However, `addEventListener` no longer works. Is there a way to pass `checkAnchorBound` as a parameter even though my listener is a bound function? If not, is there a way I can store the bound function inside of `MyObject`?

Comment: There's no reason why this would not work. Please show the error message you are receiving or make a reproducible example.

Comment: I [can't re-produce](https://jsfiddle.net/yLozjmjh/) your issue with the last snippet.