# JavaScript custom object: context of the functions

Tags: javascript, function, this

I don't have deep knowledge in JavaScript and I am going to change this situation. But some logic of JavaScript custom object function's scope doesn't have any sense for me.

For example: it is part of PhoneGap code from default project template (for Windows Phone 7).

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

It uses object literals for create the `app` object. I figure out that `initialize` and `bindEvents` functions run in `app` object scope. But what is `onDeviceReady` scope?

I tried to write next code inside of `onDeviceReady`:

```
console.log(this == document);\\out: false
```

Comment: Your use of the word "scope" is really not accurate when talking about JavaScript.  The "scope" of a function doesn't have anything to do with any object that's associated with it via property values. I think you're talking about the *context*, and that depends always on how a function is *invoked*.  If you change your `console.log()` call to just output `this` you'll get your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [addEventListener "this"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/addeventlistener-this)

Comment: @Pointy I did it and get next line - `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object]`Unfortunately, it isn't clear for me.

Comment: @Pointy You are right, `context` is more appropriate word for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is happening here:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

When the method `onDeviceReady` is called by the event emitter, the context it set to `document` because that is what the listener is bound to.

You can fix it using:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
```

Or a solution that support older browsers:

```
var self = this;
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    self.onDeviceReady.apply(self, arguments);
}, false);
```

---

If you use the utility library underscore you can use the cross browser [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', _.bind(this.onDeviceReady.bind, this), false);
```

Comment: I know that in 'onDeviceReady' is other context and I know how to bind `this` but I can't get what is `this` in my case? Because `console.log(this == document);\\out: false`.