# implement this.value in a multiple elements event listener context in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to implement `this.value` in a multiple elements add.EventListener context to activate the stuff to do on the element currently under the mouse:

```
var i = 0;
var max = 500; //ms DELAY MOUSE-IN

function time(){
    i++;
    if(i>max/10){
        i=0;

        ELEMENTS = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(i=0; i<ELEMENTS.length; i++) {        
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.height = "100px";    
        }
        clearInterval(interval1);
    }

    ELEMENTS = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(i=0; i<ELEMENTS.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].innerHTML = i;    
    }

}


window.onload = function(e) {

    ELEMENTS = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(i=0; i<ELEMENTS.length; i++) {

        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            interval1 = setInterval(time, 10); //ms intervalSpeed
        }, false);

        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
            clearInterval(interval1);
            i = 0;
            document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].innerHTML = "0";
            document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.height = "80px";
        }, false);

    }

}
```

Actually in this code there are some repetition to improve, but what i want is to IMPLEMENT **`this.value`** to control the element currently under the mouse.
Here a DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/voltk/uA5M2/

@YEM SALAT I'm sorry because I found a problem in your solution:
The timer of divs does not reset....

---

**UPDATE: I found the problem: the function time() must be included into the window load, or the 'i' on mouseout is not defined.**

Many thanks to YemSalat for his help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/the-value-of-this-within-the-handler-using-addeventlistener seems similar, it might answer your question

Comment: im new to javascript, I'm looking your link but it is a bit difficult for me to understand... Can you show me some example please?

Comment: I added an example to my answer. PS don't forget to accept if it answered your question ;)

Comment: If your question is resolved - please accept an answer; if "the answer" isn't below write it yourself and accept that but _don't edit the question to say the question is resolved_. Also don't use your question as a means of writing to an individual - use comments for that.

Comment: Omg I forget to remove the [resolved].. Please look that i have found one problem: the i = 0 on mouseout does not want to be resetted... Look the other comments...

Comment: here the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/voltk/Vr6RE/6/

Comment: Found the problem, see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to bind the event listener callback to the current DOM element.
Otherwise, *this* will refer to the global scope (browser window)

From your example:

```
var _div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i];

_div.addEventListener('mouseout', (function(){
            clearInterval(interval1);
            i = 0;
            this.innerHTML = "0";
            this.style.height = "80px";
        }).bind(_div), false);
    }   
}
```

Something like that.

EDIT: added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zAMK3/3/

Comment: in your JsFiddle the mouse delay does not work! Please have a look in my second JSFiddle posted: http://jsfiddle.net/voltk/Vr6RE/

Comment: I updated your example to use setTimeout instead: http://jsfiddle.net/zAMK3/3/
 this proves that the code works, other issues may not be related to the topic of this question

Comment: no bro, this is different from what i want... I want it exactly like my 2° example, the only modify to do is the control more than 1 div!

Comment: You'll need to bind 'time()' to the current element as well then: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr6RE/4/

Comment: Oh i found a problem!!! Each div does not reset its timer... this is terrible....

Comment: Try yourself to set the interval speed LOW from 10 to 100ms, and pay attention: you can see the mistake...

Comment: On mouseout, the 'i' does not reset on '0'  ( 1 = 0 )