# I can't call a function that I've assigned to a element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import shortid from "shortid";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    text: ""
  };

  handleTextChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  };

  addItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      text: this.state.text,
      key: shortid.generate()
    };
    const newItems = [newItem, ...this.state.items];
    this.setState({
      items: newItems,
      text: ""
    });
  };

  deleteItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Can't reach this");
  };

  render() {
    const items = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <li onClick={this.deleteItem} key={item.key}>
          {item.text}
        </li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="appMain">
        <div className="formWrapper">
          <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
            <input
              placeholder="Enter task: "
              onChange={this.handleTextChange}
              value={this.state.text}
            />
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="listWrapper">
          <ul>{items}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call the 'deleteItem' function when the elements are clicked. I'm checking this with a console.log inside the function. However it's not reaching that when I click on the element? I know it's probably a simple fix, but I've been stuck on it for a while now. can anyone help?

Comment: Would you mind adding this in codesandbox or fidler?

Comment: what about `onClick={ () => this.deleteItem }`

Comment: @Mobeen https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-firefly-h3735

Comment: @SethLutske this also doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421353/javascript-onclick-not-firing-when-assigned-inside-of-array-map

Answer (score 2):

Update your items render code to following:

```
const items = this.state.items.map(item => {
   return (
     <li onClick={this.deleteItem} key={item.key}>
       {item.text}
     </li>
   );
 });
```

Notice the change from function to ES6 arrow syntax usage. For your case: `this` inside function won't be referring to `class` but `map` function.

Full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-hopper-z09d1

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're using a normal function inside `.map` which don't have access to component `this`. So you're `onClick` is not invoking delete function if you replace with an arrow function it works.

something like this:

```
const items = this.state.items.map(item => {
      return (
        <li onClick={this.deleteItem} key={item.key}>
          {item.text}
        </li>
      );
    });
```

and working [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-frog-tzv8l)