# Prevent function from invoking until flag get set to true

Tags: javascript, css

I have created pretty easy gallery. The elements gets their transform position increased or decreased on click using

```
 function pushIt(max, target, index, count) {

    if (count == max ) {
      target[index -1].addEventListener("transitionend",turnOf,false);
      return;
   }

   var tmp                  = target[index];
   var matrix               = window.getComputedStyle(tmp).getPropertyValue("transform");
   var translate_left       = matrix.split(",")[4];
   var translate_top        = matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0]-215;
   tmp.style.transform      = "translate3d(" + translate_left + "px," + translate_top + "px,0)";
   setTimeout(function(){
    pushIt( max, target, index + 1, count + 1 );
   },50)
 } 
function turnOf(){
  running = false;
  this.removeEventListener(turnOf);
 }
```

Everything is working fine , but the problem is , when i click xxx time rly fast , it gets destroyed and does unwanted behavior. I am using flag, so the function can be called only when "running" is false , which i return back to false when the transition of the last element that should be moved is over. It works on the first few clicks  , but fast clicking ruins it and break whole script.

Live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/chaLdjxz/11/) ( click rly fast xxx times to see the behavior )

What could cause this? The flag is only set only when the transition ends, so why the function gets invoked ? Is there a way how to fix it , or shoud i use brute force ( promises ) for this?

Comment: a few things i notice off the bat is that removeEventListener takes the event type and the callback, not just the callback.  secondly, you need to bind the listener to an object to ensure 'this' in the object is what you think it is.  check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/the-value-of-this-within-the-handler-using-addeventlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be your problem:

```
function turnOf(){
  running = false;
  //this.removeEventListener(turnOf);
  this.removeEventListener("transitionend", turnOf);
 }
```