# Why doesn't bind(object) binds this to object inside anoynamous function?

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener

I am pretty new to javascript, and i am facing some problem understanding why my first code is not working as expected. I have read a few articles on "this", but it didn't help.

```
  var user_obj = {
      some_func : function () {
          alert("hello");
   }}
```

**First code:**

Here i am attaching an event listener to some element called elem. The attached function is a property of user_obj, but when i execute it, it gives me error "TypeError: this.some_func is undefined". My doubt is when i am using bind to explicitly bind this to user_obj, why is it giving this error.

```
document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener("click",(function () {this.some_func.bind(user_obj)})());
```

**Second Code:**

This works as expected.

```
document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener("click",this.some_func.bind(user_obj));
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The value of "this" within the handler using addEventListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/the-value-of-this-within-the-handler-using-addeventlistener)

Comment: In both examples, this refers to the element being clicked. Which doesn't seem to have the `some_func` function. So using bind won't do anything.
Instead you want to bind the element to the `some_func` function `user_obj.some_func.bind(this)`.

Comment: The whole IIFE `(function () {this.some_func.bind(user_obj)})()` is evaluated to `undefined`, because it returns nothing explicitly. A missing `return` statement leads to an implicit `return undefined`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I understand what you are trying to say, but my second code is solving my problem, how can that be possible?

Comment: OP - are you sure your examples work? https://jsbin.com/kugavacidu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind()` change the value of `this` inside the function, not outside.

In your first example the anonymous function use `this` to refer to global object.

If you want the anonymous function uses `this` to refers to `user_obj` you need to `bind` the anonymous function to `user_obj`, not `some_func()`, also because `some_func()` doesn't use `this`, so there is no need to bind it.

Look at the example: it prints the value of `this` in the anonymous function, first time binding it to `user_obj`, second time without binding

```js
var user_obj = {
  some_func : function () {alert("hello");}
};
        
document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener("click",(function () {console.log(this)}.bind(user_obj))());

document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener("click",(function () {console.log(this)})());
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Your second example works also without the `bind()`, because again it changes the value inside the function, where `this` isn't used. But since in your second example the call to the function isn't in an anonymous function, the value of `this` doesn't change to global object

BTW, it is `getElementById()`, not `getElementByID()` (please notice the **d** of **Id**)