# TypeScript - How to access the class instance from event handler method

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the code snippet below, I have a **TypeScript class** and the instance method `buz` is the listener for canvas' `click` event.

`this` keyword in `buz` method refers to the event's target object(canvas).

How to get access to the `foo` instance from the `buz` method?

```
    class Foo {
        constructor(private _canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, private _message: string) {

        }

        public bar(): void {
            this._canvas.addEventListener(`click`, this.buz);
        }

        private buz(e: MouseEvent): void {
            console.info(`After click event, 'this' refers to canvas and not to the instance of Foo:`);
            console.info(this);
            console.warn(`Message is: "${this._message}"`); // error
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');
        let foo = new Foo(canvas, "Hello World");
        foo.bar();
    });
```

My `tsconfig.json` has these settings:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "sourceMap": true
},
```

Comment: `this.buz.bind(this)` or `() => this.buz()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The value of "this" within the handler using addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/the-value-of-this-within-the-handler-using-addeventlistener)

Comment: @AndrewLi  Very similar to that but this one is using TS and its arrow functions. No need for `bind`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your context is lost in the `buz` method when you pass it as a parameter. You can use arrow functions to achieve that. Arrow functions will save the context.

```
public bar(): void {
    this._canvas.addEventListener(`click`, (evt) => this.buz(evt));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed my method call to this:

`this._canvas.addEventListener('click', evt => this.buz(evt));`

Comment: you save my day