# Why typescript don't find those method in phaser?

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I've started a small game with Phaser and typescript.

I've one object that reacts on a binding:

```
export default class Park extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
  poweredUp = true
  constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, parkName: string, toggleKey: string) {
    super(scene, scene.cameras.main.width / 2, scene.cameras.main.height / 2, parkName)
    scene.add.existing(this)
    scene.physics.add.existing(this)
    scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup-' + toggleKey, this.togglePower)
  }

  togglePower() {
    console.log('toggle')
    if (this.poweredUp) {
      this.powerOff()
    } else {
      this.powerOn()
    }
    this.poweredUp = !this.poweredUp
  }

  powerOff() {
    this.tint = 0xf54242
  }

  powerOn() {
    this.clearTint()
  }
}
```

When I hit the key, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.powerOn is not a function
    at KeyboardPlugin../src/scripts/objects/park.ts.Park.togglePower
```

but I don't understand, to me it appears that the function is well defined. Is there something I'm missing because of Phaser?

**EDIT** If I print `this` in togglePower, it appears that I get a  `KeyboardPlugin`.  What should I do to access my object?

Comment: what do you mean powerOn is defined on my current class, not on Sprite? When I do this, VSCode even complains

Answer (score 0):

Well. I understood, nothing to do with phaser:

You have to bind your event as described here:
[TypeScript - How to access the class instance from event handler method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606399/typescript-how-to-access-the-class-instance-from-event-handler-method)

So in my case, I need to have this:

```
scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup-' + toggleKey, this.togglePower)
```

transformed into this:

```
scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup-' + toggleKey, ()=>this.togglePower())
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont send the context as parameter, all `this` keyword inside `togglePower()` method will refer to the `KeyboardPlugin` object (or any other built-in script),

so you need to send your object as context parameter (the third parameter), and all you need is just to type `this` for the third parameter, because `this` keyword inside your constructor are still refer to your own object.

```
scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup-' + toggleKey, this.togglePower, this);
```

or to make it easier for you to understand, you can save your object to variable first before send it as parameter.

```
var yourObject = this;
scene.input.keyboard.on('keyup-' + toggleKey, this.togglePower, yourObject);
```