# VueJS error "Uncaught TypeError: this.sendDrag is not a function" in mounted ()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I can't figure out why `this.sendDrag('started')` returns this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: this.sendDrag is not a function"

```
  methods: {
    sendDrag (val) {
      console.log(val)
    }
[...]



    mounted () {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$refs.flickity.on('dragStart', function () {
            this.stageDragging = true
            this.sendDrag('started')
          })
```

What causes the error and how to fix it?

Comment: i think it is because this scoping. U could use arrow function ... or use self helper. I mean arrow function insted of function()

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Here is the solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55836450/10251861

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to capture the value of `this` in the closure because you are calling it from a function that has a different `this`.

If you used the arrow-lambda notation `()=>{}` instead of `function()` it would capture `this` for you automatically.  And that is the real difference between the two notations.

```
mounted () {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          const that = this;
          this.$refs.flickity.on('dragStart', function () {
            that.stageDragging = true
            that.sendDrag('started')
          })
```