# target "this" on addEventListener event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm dealing with a little problem..

I'm trying to modify drag-and-drop code and came across a problem, since I want to have multiple drop areas and one function for all of them.

I have this code:

```
dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault(); //preventing from default behaviour
  dropArea.classList.add("activated");
  dragText.textContent = " Release to Upload File";
});
```

And specified dropareawitth querySelector:

```
const dropArea = document.querySelector(".drag-area")
```

Now I need to modify it to work with multiple drop zones. I thought to just replace the "droparea" inside the event to "this" something like that:

```
this.classList.add("activated");
```

but it does not work. I even tried:

```
$(this).classList.add("activated");
```

Returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
```

Any solutions? I'm stuck...

Comment: it is related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338599/the-value-of-this-within-the-handler-using-addeventlistener

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` instead, or don't use arrow functions.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:jquery]? You don't seem to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

As your event handler is an arrow function, the value of `this` is not influenced by the caller, so you cannot use it to get the DOM element. You can use `event.target`.

```
event.target.classList.add("activated");
```

As to your final attempt: `$()` does not return a DOM element, but an array-like "jQuery" collection object, which doesn't have such properties as `classList`.

Comment: what does ```this``` represent in an arrow function?

Comment: For arrow functions, `this` is determined by the function execution context *around* it. If this is a top-level context, then `this` will be `undefined` or the global object. But it is not influenced by the actual call. It just has the same `this` as the immediately surrounding code would have.

Comment: @seriously See [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)