# How can I run a function with an unavailable DOM object?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I want to run a function to remove a button's parent element. parent element after getting it with

```
let rem_display_btn1 = document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1');
```

like this

```
let rem_display_btn1 = document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1');
rem_display_btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let parentEl = rem_display_btn1.parentElement.parentElement;
    parentEl.remove();
});
```

The problem now is that the initial moment the script loads in the HTML file, the button is not yet there.
That is: **rem_display_btn1** is produced after another function is run and that function it depends on those not run on **window.onload**

I will also display the function below in case it will be of help:

```
// Cart list Table Element
let cart_list = document.getElementById('cart_list');
let numy = 0;

let htmlTR = '';

let cartUpdater = () => {

    cart_list.innerHTML = "";
    htmlTR = ''
    numy = 0;

    for(let a = 0; a < cart.length; a++) {
        
        cart_list.innerHTML = "";
        numy++;
        htmlTR += `<tr id="htmlTR_ID${numy}">`;
        htmlTR += `<td style="width: 7%;">${numy}</td>`;
        htmlTR += `<td style="width: 25%;">${cart[a].name}</td>`;
        htmlTR += `<td style="width: 25%;">${cart[a].price}</td>`;
        htmlTR += `<td style="width: 15%; padding-left: 23px;"><button>-</button>1<button>+</button></td>`;
        htmlTR += '</tr>';
        console.log(htmlTR)
        cart_list.innerHTML += htmlTR;
    }

    for(let b = 0; b < cart.length; b++) {

        var remBtn_TD = document.createElement('td');
        remBtn_TD.style.width = '25%';
        var remBtn = document.createElement('button');
        remBtn.classList.add('rem_btn_');
        // Where the button element gets the **id: rem_display_btn1**
        // so I'm choosing the first button that is produced
        remBtn.id = `rem_display_btn rem_display_btn${b + 1}`;
        remBtn.innerHTML = 'remove';
        
        remBtn_TD.appendChild(remBtn);

        console.log(cart_list.children[0].children[b]);
        cart_list.children[0].children[b].appendChild(remBtn_TD);        
    }

}
```

I've tried adding an if statement after the **cartUpdater() function** to check for **document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1')** before getting the element into a variable but even then it still doesn't exist

```
if (document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1')) {
    let rem_display_btn1 = document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1');
    rem_display_btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let parentEl = rem_display_btn1.parentElement.parentElement;
        parentEl.remove();
    });
} else {
    console.log('Not There')
}
```

I'm thinking if there's a way to get the current state of the HTML/WebPage in total, so I also tried putting the if statement in a setTimeout and setInterval function but neither of them worked as well. The thing is I'm sure the is a way for this to work, I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in anticipation.

Adding the setInterval function:

```
setInterval(() => {
    if (document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1')) {
        let rem_display_btn1 = document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1');
        rem_display_btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let parentEl = rem_display_btn1.parentElement.parentElement;
            parentEl.remove();
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Not There')
    }
}, 4000);
```

For the setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if (document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1')) {
        let rem_display_btn1 = document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1');
        rem_display_btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let parentEl = rem_display_btn1.parentElement.parentElement;
            parentEl.remove();
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Not There')
    }    
}, 9000);
```

I used a longer time for the set timeout so I can run the cartUpdater() function before I get the rem_display_btn1 button

Comment: Please show how you tried to use `setTimeout` and/or `setInterval`.

Comment: I have added the setTimeout and setInterval functions

Comment: In addition to provided answers, I think that you can also use an EventListener to notify when an element is added

Comment: event delegation OR bind the event when the button is created.

Comment: @CristianTraìna how can I do that, please?

Comment: @epascarello by the time it's bonded the javascript script has already loaded and does not have the element in it's DOM list

Comment: @UkanahDean That is why I said event delegation or bind the event when you create the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the variable referencing the button at all:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   // Dropped: let rem_display_btn1 = document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1'); 
   document.getElementById('rem_display_btn1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let parentEl = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
            // Do not use 'this' to reference the button;
            //   Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270771/
        parentEl.remove();
   });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="rem_display_btn1">Remove</button>
</div>
```

**Alternative 1 (Add event handler through the code that dynamically creates an element)**

In case the element you want to attach the event handler to ( ie . `rem_display_btn1`) is inserted dynamically at some unspecified time after the document has initially been loaded, use the html attributes for event handlers:

```js
function hnd_removeButton (e) {
    let parentEl = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    parentEl.remove();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
     setTimeout ( () => {
         //
         // At the time you create the dynamic element, add the proper event handler.
         let e_btn = document.createElement('button')
           , e_container = document.getElementById ( 'test-anchor' )
           ;

         e_btn.setAttribute('id', 'rem_display_btn1');
         e_btn.textContent = 'Remove';
         e_btn.addEventListener('click', hnd_removeButton);

         e_container.appendChild(e_btn);
     }, 3000 ); 
});
```

```html
<div id="test-anchor">
  <div>Waiting for button to appear</div>
</div>
```

**Alternative 2 (Listen to DOM changes)**

Another option is to respond to elements added to the DOM. Current DOM API implementations provide the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface to support this task (Note: The formerly available event `DOMSubtreeModified` which would allow for writing a suitable handler too has been deprecated).

```js
function hnd_removeButton (e) {
    let parentEl = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    parentEl.remove();
}

function mobs_addClickHandler ( a_mutationsList, x_observer ) {
    for (const o_mutation of a_mutationsList ) {
        o_mutation.target.querySelector('#rem_display_btn1').addEventListener ( 'click', hnd_removeButton );
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mobs_addClickHandler)
        ;
    observer.observe ( document.getElementById ( 'test-anchor' ), { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true } );
     
    setTimeout ( () => { // Demo only - Elements being added. The click event handler is attached in the event handler for 'DOMSubtreeModified'
         //
         // At the time you create the dynamic element, add the proper event handler.
         let e_btn = document.createElement('button')
           , e_container = document.getElementById ( 'test-anchor' )
           ;

         e_btn.setAttribute('id', 'rem_display_btn1');
         e_btn.textContent = 'Remove';

         e_container.appendChild(e_btn);
     }, 3000 ); 
});
```

```html
<div id="test-anchor">
  <div>Waiting for button to appear</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just did that console log is showing error "cannot read property of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

Comment: Code corrected. It is still necessary to wait until the element `rem_display_btn1` becomes available in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. changed I again but still gave me the same error. I really don't know what to do again. I'm considering rewriting the entire code from the beginning maybe I'll see a better way to approach the problem

Comment: I've added an alternative method allowing for dynamic creation of content. It might be worth considering to use the CSS `display` property though instead of dynamic creation.

Comment: dear @collapsar, the "DOMSubtreeModified" event is deprecated and it is strictly mentioned not to use them anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent

Comment: @ShayanFaghani Thanks for pointing that out. Changed the implementation in Alternative 2 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a click listener to any parent element that exists right away (or the entire `document`) and check if the clicked element matches your button's id. This way, it does not matter if the button is added at a later point.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches("#rem_display_btn1")) return;
  e.target.parentElement.remove()
})
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="rem_display_btn1">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't give me any error but it doesn't do anything when I click the button